# Create Items via ECMA Script / JavaScript with SP.JS (CSOM)

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create Items via ECMA Script & the client sided object model (CSOM).

Unfortunately I couldnt find an answer yet, can you tell me how to create it?
I want to translate this function to the CSOM world :

```
 function Create_Hyperlink(address, description, comment) {
    var URL = address + " , " + description;
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        listName: "Hyperlinks",
        batchCmd: "New",
        valuepairs: [["URL", URL], ["Comment", comment]],
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            alert("Created");
            }
    });
 }
```

Thanks for your replies :))

Comment: just a remark... I would try to avoid the dollar-sign in your js since some sharepoint js-files use this... You can just replace your "$" with "jQuery" and it'll work also

Answer (score 2):

Learn to Google, my friend. The skill will serve you well. First hit on a search for "create list item javascript client object model" was:

[How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011.aspx)